# Replace \ from string

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to remove "" from the below string, and for that I am using

```
String orderDetailsDb =  "[{\"productId\":\"2814ff15-2fcf-4dc8-bf90-032e77a73e6b \",\"productName\":\"Garlic Oil 30 Capsules\",\"quantity\":6,\"price\":63.06,\"discount\":0,\"discountedPrice\":63.06,\"rowPrice\":\"\",\"gtinCode\":\"9324917000603\",\"accountNumber\":\"50138\",\"isPromo\":\"\"}]"

orderDetailsDb.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

but this is throwing

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are the square brackets around the string literal?  That's not valid Java.

Comment: Those backslashes aren't really there, they are just visible to escape the double quotes inside a Java string literal.

Comment: And `"\\"` doesn't represent a valid Java regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the " in your string you can replace the " but you have to escape it because of course it would close the string in your argument.

```
orderDetailsDb.replaceAll("\"", "")
```

or better use just replace

```
orderDetailsDb.replace("\"", "")
```

because replaceAll uses regex internally and you don't need a regex expression here.

the \ " in your strings are not there, they are just used to escape the "